# Magento Filter collection by create times (today, yesterday, week, hour etc)

Tags: date, magento, collections, filter

I have a custom collection that I wish to filter by created date and het entries created **"yesterday"**

**Collection Entries**

```
//dates are set in controller using
setCreatedTime(Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate());
```

**Created Yesterday (does not work)**

```
//3 products items Yesterday
//below filtering outputs incorrect entries
$collection = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();
```

I have tried, but outputs incorrect entries;

```
//thought strtotime('yesterday') would work..
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('gt' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('yesterday'))));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('gt' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day'))));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('from'=> strtotime('-1 day', time()),'to'=> time(),'datetime' => true));
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromDate));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
```

**Created Today (current Day)(works)**

```
//5 products items today with timestamp 2016-05-01 05:22:53
//below filtering outputs correct entries
$collection = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('gt' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today'))));
```

**Created past week (works)**

```
//23 products items with timestamps for this week
//below filtering outputs correct entries
$collection = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('gt' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 week'))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it addFieldToFilter to addAttributeToFilter. The below method is normally how I do date filtering on a collection. Note the date property being set to true.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_time', array(
        'from' => $fromDate,
        'to' => $toDate,
        'date' => true,
        ));
```

You can also see the query being generated for debugging by doing the following

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ash for your input

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Ash answer, see below how;

**I got entries created within the past hour**

```
$things = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();
$things->addFieldToFilter('things_type', 'view');
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(now()));
$things->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array(
    'from' => $fromDate,
    'to' => $toDate,
    'date' => true,
    ));
return count($things);
```

**and how I got yesterdays created entries;**

```
$now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
$dateStart = date('Y-m-d' . ' 00:00:00', $now);
$dateEnd = date('Y-m-d' . ' 23:59:59', $now);
$things = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();
$things->addFieldToFilter('things_type', 'view');
$things->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array('from' => $dateStart, 'to' => $dateEnd));
return count($things);
```